# Pycharm is taking lot of time/hung in the container

Tags: docker, pycharm, containers, gpu, rhel

Pycharm is taking lot of time/hung in the container.
It was working fine earlier. Verified all the configurations (heap memory etc). No issue with the pycharm IDE.
please note that the python project in the shared volume (nfs). No plugins were installed and no huge project too.
Just a small Hello World project is also taking time. Even selecting options from menu is taking time.

verified all pycharm settings and increased the heap memory.
Cleared the cache and restarted multiple times.
could see the memory is available in the container and no disk related issue even though it is on nfs.
It is a GPU running a docker container.

Expected to see faster results.